# Extending Phalcon ACL

Tags: php, security, acl, phalcon

The current ACL of phalcon is managing access between **roles**, **resources** and its **actions**. For example, if we want to allow specific role into specific resource :

```
$acl->isAllowed("Guests", "Customers", "search");
```

This check if role called "Guest" can access "Customers" controller for action "search". 
In my scenario, we also have "Role Level", for example, Admin can access all modules and controllers, but, to modify the contents, an Admin should have minimum Role Level 2. To gain access to modifying website configuration, an Admin should have Role Level 3.

In addition to role level, we also want to assign which models a role can have access to. For example, Mr. A and Mr. B both are Admins and have same levels. But, we decided only to allow Mr. A to access "Accounts" models while Mr. B can have access to "Accounts", "Personnel", etc.

Here are my questions :

1. Does phalcon ACL support roles and levels ? Or, should I just create the custom validation?
2. What is the benefit of using ACL compared to creating similar validation functions?
3. If I have to create custom validation, where should I put it ? In the controller, or in the dispatcher ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Phalcon does not support Role based ACLs. You will have to do something yourself to cover this. The feature has however been asked for and it is in the long list of NFRs for the project :)

The way I would go about it is use a combination of Phalcon functionality and custom programming. I would add everything to a base controller in the `beforeExecuteRoute` function so that whenever something is to be dispatched ACL is checked.

In a similar project to yours, I created two tables in my database:

```
Groups
------
group_id     <- 2
group_name   <- Admins
```

and have an ACL table that maps all actions to a group like so

```
ACL
---
group_id        <- 2
acl_controller  <- Customers
acl_action      <- Search
```

You can easily extend this to have a collection of controller/action pairs to map to a Role. From there you can just create a simple function that would load the role based resources.

It is a bit of a workaround but it works.

Comment: And when we need to get all allowed controllers/actions for the current user privileges?! If we need to create a menu with the allowed controllers for example, did you came across this task before?! How did you solved it Nikolaos?

Comment: I created a class that would load all these resources and registered it in the DI container. Then I set some functions that would quickly get me the information needed. For instance in the example above I would call a function `getACLByGroup()` and that would give me what I need. To extend that to what you want, you can create a function that will return an array or a JSON string and then your controller can parse that as a menu.

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos Thanks and sorry for late reply. I see, phalcon yet to support it and create custom code seem the only way.

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos Did you follow the suggested solution or used some other method? Good to know the challenges if any?

Comment: @Ima I never had any issues with this approach. A table for resources (URLs) and a table for groups. Link the two together and the ACL is there. All I had to was introduce caching to reduce the hits to the database.